# Why addLast() not working properly

Tags: java, collections, deque

I created a DeQueue as follws

```
Deque<Integer> deque = new ArrayDeque<Integer>(8);

// use add() method to add elements in the deque
deque.add(20);
deque.add(30);
deque.addLast(12);
deque.add(18);        
deque.addFirst(22);
deque.add(24);

// let us print all the elements available in deque
for (Integer number : deque) {
    System.out.println("Number = " + number);
}
```

The expected output is:

```
Number = 22
Number = 20
Number = 30
Number = 18
Number = 24
Number = 12
```

But the actual output is :

```
Number = 22
Number = 20
Number = 30
Number = 12
Number = 18
Number = 24
```

Anybody please explain this?

Comment: What do you think `addLast()` does? Why do you think so?

Comment: Could **you** explain why you expected that output?

Answer (score 5):

`addLast` doesn't somehow maintain a notion of "this should be last" forever - it just adds to the end of the current dequeue. It's equivalent to `add`, [as documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#addLast-E-).

So if we look at the values at each step, we have:

```
deque.add(20);      // Contents: 20
deque.add(30);      // Contents: 20, 30
deque.addLast(12);  // Contents: 20, 30, 12
deque.add(18);      // Contents: 20, 30, 12, 18
deque.addFirst(22); // Contents: 22, 20, 30, 12, 18
deque.add(24);      // Contents: 22, 20, 30, 12, 18, 24
```

... which exactly corresponds to the output you got.

Answer (score 3):

The `addLast` method adds to the last position relative to **the current deque**, not absolutely:

```
deque.add(20);      // [20]
deque.add(30);      // [20, 30]
deque.addLast(12);  // [20, 30, 12] <- 12 is last
deque.add(18);      // [20, 30, 12, 18]
deque.addFirst(22); // [22, 20, 30, 12, 18]
deque.add(24);      // [22, 20, 30, 12, 18, 24]
```

12 was the last element when you only had `[20, 30]` but then you are adding other elements, so it won't be the last one anymore.

So, if you want that value to be the last one, you need to call `addLast` after all other calls.

**UPDATE**

If you have a look at the source code of `ArrayDeque`:

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    addLast(e);
    return true;
}
```

So, the `addLast` does the same thing as `add`: It adds at the end of the **current** deque, which means that once you add other elements, the one added with `addLast` won't be the last one anymore.

Comment: *So, the addLast does the same thing as add*. Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: @CKing From a code point of view yes, it's the other way. From a logical point of view, it's the exact same concept: the two methods do the same thing.

Comment: @BackSlash If add() & addLast() are equivalent, then what is the propose of these 2 methods?

Comment: @chk.buddi You should ask Oracle! Actually, the `addLast` method is defined inside the `Deque` interface, which means that each subclass can have a different implementation. For `ArrayDeque` `addLast` and `add` methods do the same thing, for other implementations they could do different things. It seems that at the moment all implementations are like this though.

Comment: @BackSlash Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

> Anybody please explain this?

You called `addLast` when there were only 2 elements in the queue. The element passed to `addLast` was therefore added at position 3.

If you want `12` to be added to the end of the `Dequeue`, call `addLast` after you add `24` to the `Dequeue`

Answer (score 1):

This is because as JAVA Doc states, `addLast` and `add` are equivalent : [addLast(E e)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#addLast%28E%29). Hence, consider that you are simply adding 12 to the `deque`. Adding another integer to the deque won't ensure that 12 is supposed to be the last element always.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to explain the order of events,

```
1. 1st addition : 20    
2. 2nd addition: 20, 30
3. 3rd addition: 20, 30, 12 -- 12 added to the last
4. 3rd addition: 20, 30, 12
5. 4th addition: 20, 30, 12, 18
6. 5th addition: 22, 20, 30, 12, 18 -- 22 added to the first
7. 6th addition: 22, 20, 30, 12, 18, 24
```

Hope that explains